# Android markers disapear after recompiling the application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markers

Hi I am working on google maps and more specifically on setting some markers when the user clicks on the map. The problem is that whenever I re-run the activity or re-compile the application the markers disappear from the map. Any advice on that. Please help. Thank you

Here is my code where the markers are created on the onmapclick event.

```
gMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {

    gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
      .title("BAR")
      .snippet("DRINKS")
      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))); 
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of `Marker`s as you think of of Android `View`s. If you re-run the application, user and password `EditText`s that were previously entered are not filled anymore.

Use some kind of persistance to achive it. Check out your [storage options here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).